# Is there a way to use EntityManager to get entity as it is in DB instead of context without using read-only hint?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have a method, that needs to check a field as it is stored in the database. However, the field is already modified in the persistent context and differs from the value stored in the DB.

I tried using read-only hint and it worked in that way, but due to some performance issues I had to drop that solution:

```
entityManager.find(clazz, id, Collections.singletonMap(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, HintValues.TRUE))
```

Is there a way to access value stored in DB without changing the context? I tried some combinations of `detach()`, `merge()`, `persist()` methods of `EntityManager`, but the context always seems to be changed in the end.

Comment: `changing the context` - what does it mean?

Comment: The point of the EntityManager is it presents a unit of work with caching. If you don't want your changes visible, use a separate read-only EntityManager context, refresh the entity to remove the changes. Alternatively, you can have the query build an unmanaged instance from the DB data using a constructor query "select package.Entity(e.attr1, e.attr2, ..) from Entity e". JPA states objects built from constructor queries are not managed, even if they are entity classes.